# Delphi - page transition scrolling with a wipe

Tags: delphi, scroll, transition

I have some codding/performance problem and I'm stuck.

I have an application in Delphi that needs to have a page transition between screens like page scrolling with a wipe.

I'm using the BitBlt function which I thought it was the fastest, but I still can't get smooth transitions like we can see on web pages or on mobile.

I know that my screen is larger (1920x1080) but still it should be possible in some way.

Here is my code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  imgFirst, imgSecond, imgTmp : TBitmap;
  i, step : integer;
  frejmovi : Array[1..160] of TBitmap;
begin
  imgFirst := TBitmap.Create;
  imgFirst.LoadFromFile('C:\TransitionTest\bg1.bmp');
  imgSecond := TBitmap.Create;
  imgSecond.LoadFromFile('C:\TransitionTest\bg2.bmp');
  imgTmp := TBitmap.Create;

  step := 24;
  for i := 1 to 80 do
  begin
    imgTmp.Assign(imgFirst);
    BitBlt(imgTmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, i * step, 1080, imgSecond.Canvas.Handle, 1920 - i * step, 0, srcCopy);
    BitBlt(imgTmp.Canvas.Handle, i * step, 0, 1920 - (i * step), 1080, imgFirst.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, srcCopy);
    BitBlt(Form1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, imgTmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, srcCopy);
    //Sleep(5);
  end;
end;
```

I've tried different values for step and max value in for loop but with no luck. If I put a small step (for example 2px), it even hangs.

I need smooth transition like on slot machines. My app is a similar project. And I think if I get it done right on large screen it will work for sure on smaller images 300x300 px.

I'm open for any suggestions GDI, DIRECTX, ....

The application must be in Delphi (rewriting old code), but example how to solve this from C#, C++, ... Can also help me I think.

At the end I should be able to have smooth scrolling of area that will be 1530x870 px.

I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code for the timer that should start page transition.

```
for i := 0 to 1919 do
begin
  timeend := 0;
  QueryPerformanceCounter(timestart);
  repeat
    QueryPerformanceCounter(timeend);
    timelap :=  timeend - timestart;
  until (timelap > 200);
  fx := i;
  invalidate;
end;
```

But result is that pages are just replaced without moving second page to the right while pushing first page.

Thanks....

Comment: (1) You must only draw in the `WM_PAINT` handler, that is, the form's `OnPaint` handler. (2) To initiate a repaint, do an `Invalidate`. You can do this from a timer with an `Interval` of `30`, say. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912274/282848 Also, more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72131133/282848

Comment: I'd almost say this Q is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/72131133/282848

Comment: Wow, that was fast. :-) Thank you.

Code from second link is working smoothly. I'm looking the code from the first one.
I have two things here. The initial image is static. They don't move to the right as I move the mouse. Second image should push the first image out of the screen (for example to the right) not just write over them.
And the second thing, I'm not sure how to implement timer so when the user click on button transition is started.

Comment: OK, I've solved first thing regarding push of the first image.

Comment: Have you considered switching from VCL to FireMonkey? FireMonkey offers easy use of many effects and filters. If you have installed Sample projects with Delphi you may want to check `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\TabSlideTransition` or `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\FireFlow` for instance.

Comment: (Personally, I'd never recommend anyone to migrate from VCL to FMX.)

Comment: Switching to FireMonkey is not option for me. I think that I'm close to solve this. Just need to fix this timer issue.